# Killing an executable with wrong architecture in a noninteractive session

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows build system that runs a Jenkins agent as a non-interactive service. One of the build scripts built an ARM64 targeted test executable and executed it.

The process does not show up in the process list, because it cannot run, but from the point of view of the calling process, it it still running, so the build process just hangs. I'd expect that it is trying to display a dialog, but since it is in a non-interactive session, this doesn't work.

How can I kill such a process, short of a reboot?

Current setup is Windows 7, but this will be replaced with a Windows Server 2016 setup shortly, so if the same problem exists there, it would be good to know how to solve it there as well.

Comment: Anything that runs should either show up as a process in the processes tab, or if it is a service, it should run as a service, but even services are processes. It just then probably shows as one of the svchost.exe processes. Do note, you have to visit the processes tab (win7) / Details tab (win 8, 10, 2012, 2016) to see all of them. Process hacker is probably able to identify your program when it is launched through svchost.exe.

Comment: @LPChip, I can see the parent process (nmake.exe), but not the process itself (bzip2.exe) in Process Manager.

Comment: Are you sure it is not nmake that does all the things? Have you tried to kill it and see what happens?

Comment: @LPChip, yes, I've killed nmake.exe, which will allow the build process to terminate, but bzip2.exe was started with input and output redirected, and these handles remained open.

Comment: Have you enabled "Show processes for all users?"

Comment: @LPChip, yes, otherwise I could not see the nmake.exe process either, as it's a different session.